# SQLite android - an if condition that checks whether column name equals a certain value then executes the if statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to update the value of a boolean field in an sqlite database column, i first want to check if the value of the field is 0 then if yes it should update the value to 1.

This is what i have so far:

```
String where = "student_number=?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{compare};
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("student_number", 1);

if ("student_number" == "0") {
    db.update("course1", cv, where, whereArgs);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Attendance Taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Attendance already registered.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But it's not updating, i think the problem is with the if condition.

Comment: this will never evaluate as true : `if("student_number" == "0") `

Comment: how can i check whether the value is a 0 and not a 1, in order for it to only update once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `if("student_number" == "0")` you are comparing strings (and in bad way, strings should be compared with equals), that will always be false, you are not comparing the value of the field student_number.

Although your code was correct it has not sense. You set the field to 1 and then you check if the value is 0.

What you are triying to do can be done with a simple query.

`"UPDATE table SET student_number = '1' WHERE student_number = '0' AND other_condition = 'x'"`

That's ok but there is no need to check if the previous value was 0, you could update it anyway, because it can only be true or false.

`"UPDATE table SET student_number = '1' WHERE other_condition = 'x'"`

Both are correct but don't forget to add some where clause, if you forget all the rows will be updated.

EDIT: I'm not telling you to use raw queries, it's better to use SQLiteDatabase methods like update(), I just wanted to show you the examples queries.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but i need it to display a toast if the value is already 1, how can i achieve that?

Comment: Then run the first query with SQLiteDatabase update method. If it returns zero no rows was updated.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html